# Detect real screen resolution (ignoring browser zoom etc.)

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, screen-resolution

I need to get the real screen resolution using JavaScript (client-side at least), but having issues with both IE and Firefox as they tend to change this when you use the browser's built-in zoom.

How can this be done in a cross-browser friendly manner?

Comment: Please show some code and an example how the values change

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDimension() {
  var width = 0, height = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    height = window.innerHeight;
    width = window.innerWidth;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    height = document.body.clientHeight;
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
  }
  window.alert( 'Width = ' + width + 'Height = ' + height);
}
```

or (jquery)

```
height    = $(window).height();
width    = $(window).width();
```

Comment: as far as zoom goes = you could easily get the zoom level from the document.body.style.zoom (somthing like that) and work it into the equation.

Comment: I doubt that those values change with zooming in the first place, which is why I'd like to see the OP's code first - there must be something else going on

Comment: Hmm - yeah I don't know for sure if they would change on zoom (be easy to find out tho ;). OP - code?

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work with most browser if you use the zoom (CTRL+/CTRL-) of the browser. Then the calculation will be relative to the zoom level which I cannot access. Quite annoying!

Comment: Yes but you should be able to obtain the current zoom level via document.body.style.zoom - just multiply your current dimensions by the zoom factor and you should have your unzoomed resolution. Im in a car right now and cant test it... but i think it should work.

Comment: Problem is that document.body.style.zoom is not supported by all browsers (e.g. Firefox). So won't solve the case unfortunately!

Comment: shouldnt the OR || be AND && ?

|| will be a bit more efficient but might lead to problems if some script defines document.body.clientHeight but not document.body.clientWidth in a browser that doesnt support the functionality.

Comment: and i just realized that the () around the || will lead to the full or being executed if the first part returns false,
so there is no efficiency gain