# Get actual screen resolution( apart of browser zoom) in IE & Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, zooming

I want JavaScript code to get real screen resolution(not browser) in Firefox & IE which is not effected with browser zoom or resize. I have search through stackoverflow, but could't get working solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342805/detect-real-screen-resolution-ignoring-browser-zoom-etc?answertab=votes#tab-top) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557404/get-screen-resolution-independent-of-zoom-in-firefox/34368907). I have added jsFiddel which can get real screen size with chrome. Could anyone provide the better solution to get real screen size in FireFox & IE.

https://jsfiddle.net/k6jsp43f/3/

```
my screen resolution : <p id="demo"></p>

function getScreenSize(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  screen.width + " : " +   screen.height;
}

getScreenSize();
```

try the get real screen resolution of the screen even browser zoom in, zoom out & by resizing the window.

I need plain javascript solution. Thank you.

Comment: It's not accurate depending on how you want to look at it in Chrome either, I'm on a HDPI screen and it's only reporting half the pixels. It's tell me `2560 : 1440` but it's *technically* double (5K monitor)

Comment: Yes jorg , but the above value will not change on browser zoom in chrome. But in firefox it will change with browser zoom. thanks for let me that also.

Comment: I suppose you can try and get the zoom level too, and calculate from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers. I know it's old, but it might be useful.

Comment: thanks jorg. cant get 100% good solution form that. still looking some function.